# Menu click in user control in master page not working from content page

Tags: asp.net, user-controls, master-pages

I had a menu in user control (menu.ascx) in master page (mainmaster.master). That menu is populated dynamically.

Now we have a content page that uses mainmaster.master has iframe. Now I want to click on menu in masterpage (which in turn is in user control) i.e products
and want to open products.aspx in that iframe.

Answer (score 0):

Your user control, master page and content page all get rendered to a single HTML page, so you could use client-side script to set the source of the `iframe`.

Something along the lines of this:

**jQuery**

```
$(function() {
   $('.menuItem').click(function(e) { 
      e.preventDefault();
      $('#iframe').attr("src", $(this).attr("href"));
   });
});
```

**HTML**

```
<a href="products.aspx" class="menuItem">Products</a>

<iframe id="iframe" src="default.aspx" />
```

**Working Demo**

[**Here's a little demo on jsfiddle.net**](http://jsfiddle.net/Town/k5QmR/).